# Undefined offset php cargar datos desde Excel

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

Tengo el siguiente código el cual utilizo para cargar datos desde un archivo Excel a una base de datos, pero al momento de ingresar los datos me aparece un error o warning indicando Undefined offset por cada linea del arreglo, e intentado modificar la estructura de la base de datos pero el error es el mismo aunque los datos si quedan cargados en la BD sigue apareciendo el mensaje.

```
require_once APPPATH.'/third_party/Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php';

use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;  
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;

//Con las lineas anteriores cargamos la librería

class cargaAgenda extends  CI_Controller{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index(){
        //aquí se carga el diseño
        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->model('loginm'); //llamo al modelo loginm para traer  la funcion Traer datos y poder consultar los datos de usuario
        $nombres['nombre'] = $this->loginm->TraerDatos($_SESSION['usuarios']);  //    comprobamos que el usuario exista en la base de datos y la password ingresada sea correcta
        $this->load->view('layouts/menu', $nombres);
        $this->load->view('agenda/cargaAgenda');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');        

    }

    public function cargar_agenda(){


        if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {


            $pathinfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);


            if (($pathinfo['extension'] == 'xlsx' || $pathinfo['extension'] == 'xls') 
            && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0 ) {

                // Nombre Temporal del Archivo
                $inputFileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

                //Lee el Archivo usando ReaderFactory
                $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);

                $reader->setShouldFormatDates(true);

                // Abrimos el archivo
                $reader->open($inputFileName);
                $count = 1;

                //Numero de Hojas en el Archivo
                foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
                    $logs = array(
                        'tipocarga' => 'Agenda',
                        'usuariocarga'  => $_SESSION['usuarios'],
                        'ultimacarga'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                    );

                    $this->db->replace('cargas_sistema', $logs);                    

                    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {


                        if($count > 1) {

                                $data = array(
                                   'fecha' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row[0])),
                                    'hora' => date("H:i", strtotime($row[1])),
                                    'saus_salas_sala' => $row[2],
                                    'juez' => $row[3],
                                    'acta' => $row[4],
                                    'tipo' => $row[5],
                                    'rit' => $row[6],
                                    'caratulado' => $row[7]
                                    //            'fecha_ter' => $this->input->post('fecha_ter') // dato pasado por post

                                );  
                                $this->db->insert('saus_agenda',$data);                            
                            } 
                            $count++;                      
                        } 

                    }                  

                    $reader->close();

                    echo "<a href='http://asalvarez/lion/agenda/cargaAgenda'>Carga Finalizada Volver</a>";

                } else {

                    echo "Seleccione un tipo de Archivo Valido";
                }

            } else {

                echo "Seleccione un Archivo EXCEL";

            }


        }


    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes añadir el mensaje exacto y la linea exacta donde occure el error?

Comment: edite la pregunta con una captura del error gracias.

Comment: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/#error-handling Ahí puedes ver la manera de ver más información sobre el error. Aun no habiendo usado la librería, me da la impresión de que no estás accediendo correctamente a las celdas de cada fila y de que `$row[0]` te devuelve algo más que el contenido de la primera celda ya que en los ejemplos que encuentro para acceder a las celdas usan un `getCellIetarator()` para ir recorriéndolas. https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/#looping-through-cells-using-iterators

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo en el error y el offset tu problema se encuentra en el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
<?php
foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row)
{
    if ($count > 1)
    {
        $data = array(
            'fecha' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row[0])) ,
            'hora' => date("H:i", strtotime($row[1])) ,
            'saus_salas_sala' => $row[2],
            'juez' => $row[3],
            'acta' => $row[4],
            'tipo' => $row[5],
            'rit' => $row[6],
            'caratulado' => $row[7]
        );
        $this
            ->db
            ->insert('saus_agenda', $data);
    }
    $count++;
}
```

El valor de `saus_salas_sala` que es `$row[2]` no esta siendo encontrado, mi recomendacion es que simplemente hagas un `var_dump()` de `$row` dentro del `foreach()` y antes del `if()`, para que verifiques los datos que contiene el arreglo y te des cuenta por que ese `offset` no existe dentro del `array`.

Comment: bueno el vardump me da 2 resultados que debo arreglar pero aun no encuentro la forma precisa, 1)
7 => string 'ALIANZA SEGURIDAD LIMITADA/ARRIAGADA                                                                ' algunos string vienen con espacio al final el cual intento eliminar con Trim pero no resulta y lo otro 
2) 2 => string '' (length=0) algunos string vienen en blanco y dan el error de Undefined offset.

Comment: El undefined offset es cuando no encuentra algo dentro de un arreglo, es decir, si tienes un array con índice [1] y [3] por ende si tu haces un array[2] te va a salir dicho error. Eso es lo que te está sucediendo, quieres obtener un dato que no existe. Realiza un var_dump del arreglo entero y fijate todo lo que contiene.